# How to connect Lambda Function to Nuance Mix Backend

Tags: aws-lambda, nuance

I am trying to connect a Lambda function to a Nuance dialog mix where i am not able to call the function. Can Someone help me on this...I tried the Nuance document but it is not workin

Comment: Hi Dinesh. Please provide your code and the error you get.

Comment: It has nothing to do with code .... my requirement is to how to integrate nuance mix tool with AWS lam da function